# How to Upper Case References in Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to type References in uppercase, I am using this code but still I am getting lower case References. I am using apacite formating with Bibtex file

```
\centering
\label{REFERENCES}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{Bibliography2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\label` has nothing to do with this. Use rather `\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks this worked for me

```
\centering
\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{Bibliography2}

\end{document}
```